# Python: Converting Binary Literal text file to Normal Text

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, web-crawler, utf

I have a text file in this format:

```
b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla'
b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.'
```

And I want to read those lines and covert them to

```
Chapter 1 - BlaBla
Boy's Dead.
```

and replace them on the same file.
I tried encoding and decoding already with `print(line.encode("UTF-8", "replace"))` and that didn't work

Comment: Are you certain that's the exact text in the file, and not just what the variable contains after reading the file?

Comment: `.decode('utf-8')` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings = [
    b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla',
    b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.',
]

for string in strings:
    print(string.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

--output:--
Chapter 1 – BlaBla
Boy’s Dead.
```

> and replace them on the same file.

There is no computer programming language in the world that can do that. You have to write the output to a new file, delete the old file, and rename the newfile to the oldfile.  However, python's `fileinput` module can perform that process for you:

```
import fileinput as fi
import sys

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla\n')
    f.write(b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.\n')

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)

with fi.input(
        files = 'data.txt', 
        inplace = True,
        backup = '.bak',
        mode = 'rb') as f:

    for line in f:
        string = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        print(string, end="")
```

---

```
~/python_programs$ python3.4 prog.py
b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla\n'
b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.\n'

~/python_programs$ cat data.txt
Chapter 1 – BlaBla
Boy’s Dead.
```

**Edit:**

```
import fileinput as fi
import re

pattern = r"""
    \\              #Match a literal slash...
    x               #Followed by an x...
    [a-f0-9]{2}     #Followed by any hex character, 2 times 
"""

repl = ''

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(r"b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla'", file=f)
    print(r"b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.'", file=f)

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip()) #Output goes to terminal window

with fi.input(
        files = 'data.txt', 
        inplace = True,
        backup = '.bak') as f:

    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()[2:-1]
        new_line = re.sub(pattern,  "", line, flags=re.X)
        print(new_line) #Writes to file, not your terminal window
```

---

```
~/python_programs$ python3.4 prog.py 
b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla'
b'Boy\xe2\x80\x99s Dead.'

~/python_programs$ cat data.txt
Chapter 1  BlaBla
Boys Dead.
```

Your file does not contain binary data, so you can read it (or write it) in `text mode`.  It's just a matter of escaping things correctly.

Here is the first part:

```
print(r"b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla'", file=f)
```

Python converts certain `backslash escape sequences` inside a string to something else. One of the backslash escape sequences that python converts is of the format:

```
\xNN  #=> e.g. \xe2
```

The backslash escape sequence is four characters long, but python converts the backslash escape sequence into a *single* character.

However, I need each of the four characters to be written to the sample file I created.  To keep python from converting the backslash escape sequence into one character, you can escape the beginning '\' with another '\':

```
\\xNN
```

But being lazy, I didn't want to go through your strings and escape each backslash escape sequence by hand, so I used:

```
r"...."
```

An `r string` escapes all the backslashes for you.  As a result, python writes all four characters of the `\xNN` sequence to the file.

The next problem is `replacing a backslash in a string using a regex`--I think that was your problem to begin with.  When a file contains a `\`, python reads that into a string as `\\` to represent a literal backslash.  As a result, if the file contains the four characters:

```
\xe2
```

python reads that into a string as:

```
"\\xe2"
```

which when printed looks like:

```
\xe2
```

The bottom line is: if you can see a '\' in a string that you print out, then the backslash is being escaped in the string.  To see what's really inside a string, you should always use `repr()`.

```
string = "\\xe2"
print(string)
print(repr(string))

--output:--
\xe2
'\\xe2'
```

Note that if the output has quotes around it, then you are seeing everything in the string.  If the output doesn't have quotes around it, then you can't be sure exactly what's in the string.

To construct a regex pattern that matches a literal back slash in a string, the short answer is: you need to use double the amount of back slashes that you would think.  With the string:

```
"\\xe2"
```

you would think that the pattern would be:

```
pattern = "\\x"
```

but based on the ***doubling rule***, you actually need:

```
pattern = "\\\\x"
```

And remember `r` strings?  If you use an `r` string for the pattern, then you can write what seems reasonable, and then the `r` string will escape all the slashes, doubling them:

```
pattern r"\\x"  #=> equivalent to "\\\\x"
```

Comment: Can you try writing the two lines b'Chapter 1 [...] to Dead.\n into a tempdata.txt and print line 1 of the new data.txt? For example f.write(ftemp.readline()) instead of f.write(b'Chapter 1 \xe2\x80\x93 BlaBla\n')? Thank you for your time

Comment: @seraf, I edited my example--not sure when you read it.  In any case, now I think it does what you are asking.   I've also specified an argument to `fi.input()`, which causes the original text to be written to a file called `data.txt.bak`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I did to simplify this is that I take the line I'm reading and remove first two characters and the last characters so I can do what you did on the data.txt: f.write(b'[...]\n')

Comment: @Seraf, Are you saying that the file actually contains the characters `'b` at the start of a line?  You need to post a couple of lines of your file, e.g. the output of: `$ head -n 3 data.txt`

Comment: that's exactly what I'm saying here's two lines, my thing didn't work had to study so I took a break but here's the first two lines of the Chapter 16's file:
b'Chapter 16 \xe2\x80\x93 Young Master Xiao, Looking for Death'

b'\xe2\x80\x9cEh? Brother Yulong? What\xe2\x80\x99s wrong?\xe2\x80\x9d Xiao Che quickly stood up with an alarmed look.' @7stud

Comment: Well I actually removed the b' on the beggining and the ' at the end but I still have those special characters not displaying properly. Only thing I would need is to convert for example \xe2\x80\x93 to -. I could add a function on my program to do that and replace each and single line of the chapters I'm crawling but I'm sure there's something in python that can do that for me xD

Comment: @Seraf, I need you to run the command I specified, and I want you to copy and paste the command as well as the output from the command at the bottom of your question, okay?